# Visual Studio 2008 file could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm getting this message when I try to check out a file.

> The item C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XX\XX\XX\XX.aspx could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

So far there is only 1 file that having this issue.

I tried "Get Latest Version" & "Get Specific Version"

But nothing seems to be working.  I have the file in the specific path.

Any idea of what the issue is or how to resolve it?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Hi Cece, I am using TFS
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer
Version 9.0.30729.4413

Comment: Have you checked the security of the file? If you create a new workspace, will this issue persist?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the .aspx file and select Advanced--Security to grant your account appropriate permissions:

   [image]
2. Try to create a new workspace, and perform "Get Latest", to see whether the issue persists.